# How to type a property already typed as any?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am a using a third part library that have a type as following :

```
export interface ThirdPartyNodeType {
 id: string;
 name: string;
 data: any;
}
```

Now I know what I want to put in that ThirdPartyNodeType.data :

```
export interface MyOwnDataProperties {
 foo: string;
 bar: string;
}
```

How can I tell TypeScript "I don't want this `ThirdPartyNodeType.data` to be `any` anymore it
has to be type of `MyOwnDataProperties`"?

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/wglP6N) is what you are looking for

Comment: It is not really what I was looking for as it creates a new updated interface which won't work if I want to use that third party library because it will not recognize this new interface.

Comment: You might probably want to create type definition file `*.d.ts`, see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). Please provide me with real life example an exact name of third party library

Comment: Yes it is a type definition, what you provided works !

Comment: For what scope do you want that change to take effect? Please [edit] to clarify. Do you want it to be in effect at any scope? Just a specific scope? Just a specific statement? An individual statement can be changed using a type assertion (`as`). Changing for a scope can be done using an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround if you are okay with using a wrapper around the type instead of modifying the type itself: You could subclass the interface. An example of the downsides of the workaround is that if the thirdy party interface is the type of a returned value from a function of the third party code, and you want the type to be changed to your wrapper type, you will need to use a type assertion (`as`).

```
export interface ThirdPartyNodeType {
 id: string;
 name: string;
 data: any;
}

// Instance of ThirdPartyNodeType
const a: ThirdPartyNodeType = {
    id: 'id',
    name: 'name',
    data: {}
}

// Your custom typing
export type YourData = {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

// Interface inheritance
export interface ThirdPartyNodeTypeExtension extends ThirdPartyNodeType {
    data: YourData
}

// Use your custom typing
const b: ThirdPartyNodeTypeExtension = a;

// (property) ThirdPartyNodeTypeExtension.data: YourData
b.data
```

Comment: I don't want to create a new interface. I want to override this property type and keep the same interface declared in my third party library.